# Operating System (kernel) 's effect on program instructions (at binary level)

Tags: linux, assembly, operating-system, kernel, cpu

If we don't have an operating system running on a processor - it will run the binary program (in it's machine language) we feed it. for example if it's a sequence of instruction (assuming no jump): `A B C D`; then these four instructions will simply be run one by one.

Now when we talk about OSes, the common way of talking is often - the OS/kernel takes care that that one process's instructions don't interfere with another's; and that the OS manages the access to the device. This kind of language makes it sound like there is a watchman (an independent all time alive(in the sense of executing) entity) who is looking down from the top and instructing/making sure everything is running fairly and smoothly and does whatever he needs to do for everything (other mortal processes) running.

In reality of course there is no place for such god-like position for the machine. There is only one processor (ALU), which executes instruction based on the next value in the Program Counter - this processor doesn't know or care what the instruction is.

So then, how does the OS 'takes care' of everything? Does it interleave the instructions of the programs we want to run with it's own bunch of instructions to enforce the policing? so if the instruction set for the program was `A B C D` (and assuming some of these were external device access commands) - then it might become `A X B Y C D Z`   somewhere in the memory (from where the processor fetches these instructions)? And after the last instruction it's again OS's set of instructions which copy another program or do some housekeeping..? Basically yy question is: how does OS perform it's functions - in terms of the flow of the machine instructions running on the ALU?

Comment: You may want to read [Wikipedia: Context switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) as it is the mechanism that does the instruction interleaving and also chapter "PRIVILEGED INSTRUCTIONS" in [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) as it describes how OS get's the _power_ for the god-like behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bare metal is what we call it when there is no os.  An operating system itself is a bare metal program.   The operating system is not always running on a single processor system (or even multi).  Timer based interrupts are setup for example so that every N whatever units of time the operating system gets an interrupt and can choose to for example change the foreground task, giving the illusion that many programs are running at once but really only one is (except on multi-core processors).  Also hardware interrupts are handled by the operating system, a disk needs something, memory management unit, keyboard, mouse, etc.

Multi-core just multiplies the complexity, the operating system juggles more threads that can/do run in parallel.  Once you have more things running than cores then the operating system has to swap out on some time basis who gets to run now and next just like single core.

Answer (score 2):

Architectures where you can run "proper" operating systems typically offer different operating modes for the applications and the kernel. Some instructions can only be executed in kernel mode, and if your user program attempts to run them, some sort of a notification (exception, trap, interrupt, etc.) is raised which stops executing the user code and switches to the operating system which then handles the issue. Similar mechanism works in conjunction with the memory management unit to provide virtual memory: when an instruction references a virtual address that is for some reason not accessible, a page fault occurs and control is transferred to the OS so it can take action. The OS also gets control when external events (hardware interrupts) needs servicing, such as when a device needs some attention.

Apart from the above, in a multitasking system the OS also takes control periodically so that it can manage resource allocation. This usually involves a timer interrupt.

Comment: thank you for your explanation. both answers were great but since I could only chose one as "accepted" - I chose the chronologically first.